# Auto Facebook Friend Request Respone

Tags: facebook

Is there a way to automatically accept friend requests on a Facebook account and then send them a personalised message?

Ie. go through ~25 or so requests at a time, accepting them, then sending them a message like: "Hi , message contents..."

Does anyone know if it is possible to do this already? Or is there a way I can go about making something to do it quickly?

Alternatively, is there a way to put a code for the recipient's name in a Facebook message?
Ie. Message to John: "Hi , contents..." goes to "Hi John, contents..."

Comment: sounds like managing a non-personal account here.. unless, you wouldn't want to generate a machine-styled message to your friend.. well, unless you are going to make your own greasemonkey script, you may just propose this functionality to the developer team.

Comment: No there is no API for that. And you will soon run into the limit if you keep going like that anyway